# Get all the client IDs and store them in a list in C#

Tags: c#, combobox, datasource

I am coding an application and I wish to get all the client IDs and store them in a list to show them as DataSource on a comboBox.

Like ClientId = 1, 2, 3 in a list.

```
            cln = new Client();

        List<String> getClients = new List<String>{ cln.Id };

        getClients.ElementAt(0);

        clientIdComboBox.DataSource = getClients;
```

**Edit 2:**

```
List<Client> clients = new List<Client>();
        clients.Add(new Client() { Id = "1" });
        clients.Add(new Client() { Id = "2" });

        clientIdComboBox.DataSource = clients;
```

[This is how it looks like when I added the above code. There are 2 but empty.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9Zxj.png)

Comment: If you aren't able to do something as basic as this, the best advice anyone can offer you is to go and run through some starter C# tutorials.

Comment: pls i need it for assignment

Comment: Then you need to go and learn C# by yourself. Stackoverflow is not a site for writing code for you, you need to try something and then ask here if it doesn't work.

Comment: Edited the post with code I tried

Comment: Now reply with help pelase thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

At first you wanna setup the List properly:

```
List<Client> clients = new List<Client();
clients.Add(new Client() { Id = 1});
clients.Add(new Client() { Id = 2});
[...]

clientIdComboBox.DataSource = clients;
```

Comment: but I don't want to use those Ids I need to use Ids that I already entered in the form presentation view and not showing in the combobox still I had to do it Id = "1" but still not showing